# Changing "top" css of absolute positioned element with jQuery click

Tags: jquery, css, positioning, css-position, absolute

I've got a div (#slider) that I'm using position: absolute; to allow it to span the width of the screen without having to break my wrapper code. However, I have a menu that toggles upon click of the "work" div using jQuery slideToggle. I would like to adjust the "top" property of the absolute positioned element so that it moves down when my menu slides down.

This can be viewed live at http://osephj.com/dev/

This is all using adaptive media queries, so obviously the CSS triggered by the click via jQuery would need to have media queries in it so the top position will apply appropriately for all screen sizes.

Right now, the code I have for toggling the menu is this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#worktoggle').click(function(){
     $('div.slider').css('top', 700);
     $('div.work').slideToggle(600,'swing');
     return false;
   });
});
</script>
```

This is now relocating the .slider div, but I need to be able to change the value for each media size. Also, I'd like it to match the "swing" transition at the 600 speed that the menu comes down with. Basically, how it would act if it were a block element that followed my "work" UL in the same parent element.

Comment: That is absolute basic. I don't understand why it is for everyone so hard just to look up the jQuery documentation, for basic functionality.

Comment: If it's so basic then I'm sure you wouldn't mind helping out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method is probably what your looking for.

```
$('#').css('top', 1000);
```

or [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) to add your own class to the element.

you may want to look at the [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) animation method for the transition.

You want to add this code inside your click function since you want it to change onclick.

```
$('#worktoggle').click(function(){
    $('div.toMove').css('top', 100);
    $('div.work').slideToggle(600,'swing');
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Where would I put that in this code?
        
`<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#worktoggle').click(function(){
     $('div.work').slideToggle(600,'swing');
  return false;
   });
});
</script>`

Comment: I think you should update the question with your code to make it easier to see and make comments.

Comment: No problem, make sure you bookmark [jQuery](api.jquery.com) you can find a lot of answers there.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be functioning. I updated my code on the live site. Could it be because of the media query?

Comment: When I inspected your sites code I couldn't find the element div.element. Maybe if you update the question with your live javascript the piece of HTML your trying to manipulate we can find the problem.

Comment: It's all there, I'm editing the javascript that's in the <head> of the live page.

Comment: there's no quotes around the pixel value my mistake. I updated the answer. $('div.slider').css('top', 1000);

Comment: Okay, now how can I make this toggle, just like the menu toggles, as well as change the measurements for each media size?

Comment: you want the div.slider to slide down? Are you using different css files for media types?

Comment: I'm using media queries in my css. I want the div.slider to slide down when the menu is clicked, so that the menu is visible, and then slide back up when the menu is closed. Basically, how it would act if it were a block element that followed my "work" UL in the same parent element.

Comment: take a look at this code and examples http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/. For the media queries I would use addClass and removeClass instead of css.